# Images hidden behind fixed footer

Tags: css

Please take a look at the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ellenchristine/tty3e/

Note that when you expand or contract the Results panel, the jQuery Masonry plugin populates the new space with images. However, I'm having trouble with the footer area...when you scroll to the very bottom, the last image is always partially hidden behind the fixed footer. I've tried adding margins on the footer, on the wrapper, everything, but am not getting anywhere. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove the height settings you had on #wrapper, and set a bottom padding, it appears to function as you need. The height 100% was taking up 100% of the parent, since all the elements within #wrapper were floated, and that was just the height of the display window. If you want to see that in action, put a border on #wrapper before removing the height to see the problem.

```
#wrapper {
    width:960px;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0 115px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tty3e/8/

Answer (score 0):

try `overflow:hidden` on `#wrapper`

Comment: If you tried this in the jsFiddle, you would have noticed that it doesn't work. It prevents the images from going under the footer, but it actually hides them rather than wrapping the images with #wrapper as expected.